# Fill megamenu dynamically

Tags: c#, html

I have this functions that gets categories in three levels.

- One that gets `ParentCategories`
- One that gets categories by `ParentCategoryID`
- One that gets `Subcategories` by `categoriesID`.

I want to build a megamenu looking like this site:
http://www.potterybarn.com/

HTML Markup

```
 <div>
    <asp:Repeater ID="HorizMenuRepeater" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
<ul id="mega-menu"></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
<li><a id="mBox" href="javascript:;">'<%#Eval("ParentCatName")%>'</a></li></ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate></asp:Repeater>
</div>

    <script>
        window.addEvent('domready', function () {


            new mBox.Tooltip({
                content: 'MegamenuUC',
                setStyles: { content: { padding: 15, lineHeight: 20 } },
                position: {
                    x: 'right',
                    y: 'bottom'
                },
                attach: 'mBox',
                closeOnMouseleave: true
            });

        });
</script>
    <div id="MegamenuUC" style="display:none">
<uc1:Megamenu ID="Megamenu1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

result

[image]

Code of the usercontrol

```
<ul>
<h3>Category</h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sub category</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

I want to make this dynamically, now it's just the parentcategory that is dynamic.

I need somehow pass the id to know witch parentcategory you hovered over tho pas the right id to my function that gets the categories so I can populate my usercontrol with it

Thanks

Comment: mabe use ajax, i need to pas the id without postback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it and i used a repeater to create a clean list and a jquery plugin to create megamenu

Link to jquery plugin http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/options/

Code for databind repeater with linq

```
        <div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="ParentRepeater" runat="server"  OnItemDataBound="ParentRepeater_OnItemBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <ul>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li><a><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ParentCatName") %></a>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="ParentCatRepeater" runat="server"  OnItemDataBound="ChildRepeater_OnItemBound">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <ul>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li><a><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CategoryName") %></a>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="ChildRepeater" runat="server">
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ul>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <li><a><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductName") %></a></li>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </li>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

    </div>
```

C#

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinqtoDBDataContext db = new LinqtoDBDataContext();

        ParentRepeater.DataSource = db.GetParentCategories();
        ParentRepeater.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ParentRepeater_OnItemBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            dynamic cat = e.Item.DataItem as dynamic;
            int parentcatid = Convert.ToInt32(cat.ParentCatID);

            LinqtoDBDataContext db = new LinqtoDBDataContext();

            //var cats = from c in db.Categories
            //           where c.ParentCatID == parentcatid

            //          select c;

            Repeater ParentCatRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("ParentCatRepeater") as Repeater;
            ParentCatRepeater.DataSource = db.GetCategories(parentcatid);
            ParentCatRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void ChildRepeater_OnItemBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            dynamic prod = e.Item.DataItem as dynamic;
            int catid = Convert.ToInt32(prod.CategoryID);

            LinqtoDBDataContext db = new LinqtoDBDataContext();

            Repeater ChildRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("ChildRepeater") as Repeater;
            ChildRepeater.DataSource = db.GetProductsInCategory(catid);
            ChildRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }

}
```